# Is there a formal system that proves its consistency while proving the existence of a stronger formal system that can interpret general recursion too?

Tags: incompleteness, formal-proofs

So looking at theorems like incompleteness, it is clear that such properties cannot be found from within. But when we take a more vague approach like simply requiring existence, do these restrictions still exist? So to be clearer, beyond even defining stronger systems without construction, could they then prove consistency of such a stronger system?

Comment: Gentzen's proof that PA is consistent was a "workaround" , but assumed transfinite induction to be consistent. Note also that Goedel's results are only true for sufficient powerful theories..  You are right that if we prove the consistency of PA with a stronger theory (for example ZFC) , then we have only transofrmed the question whether PA is consistent (and this continues forever if we use even more powerful theories containing the previous theory).

Comment: @Peter Yes, this is exactly what made me wonder if there were other ways to transform the problem in a weaker system, like dropping the constructive nature of looking at specific axioms to prove the existence of a consistent stronger system, while also putting it in terms of some weaker system that is able to prove its own consistency like Presburger Arithmetic.